# debuild - dependencies set but without version

Tags: debian, packaging, deb, software-packaging

Lets say I have the following package: `zs-boost_1.71.0_armhf.deb`. This is custom package that installs boost 1.71 to some custom location (assume `/opt/deps`).

I also have project that uses this library. It builds and runs fine. Now I'm packaging it. I have the following in `debian/control` file:

```sh
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
```

I build package using: `debuild -b -us -uc -aarmhf`. Package can be built and works as expected. My only problem is that its `Depends` entry in deb's `control` file is as follows:

```sh
Depends: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.9), libpq5 (>= 9.0~), zs-boost, init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~)
```

Note that zs-boost has no version. How can I fix it? Is it caused by installation to custom directory? I'd assume that if package was identified correctly, then its version should be used as well?

`debian/package.substvars` contains the following line for `shlibs`:

```sh
shlibs:Depends=libc6 (>= 2.9), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0), libuuid1 (>= 2.16), zs-boost
```

What should I do for the dependencies to be properly versioned? Note that I am not interested in providing version numbers manually, this is only one package and we have 20+ packages that are constantly updated and rebuilt and doing it by hand is out of question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a versioned dependency? Why do you expect one to be generated? Which version do you expect to b generated then?

Comment: I need versioned dependency because I version packages and versions change often and our packages won't necessarily work with older versions of packages. I expect that dependency will look like "zs-boost (>= 1.71.0)". I expect that version will generated because it is generated for other libraries/packages. I even tried to to add `override_dh_makeshlibs: / dh_makeshlibs -V` to "debian/rules", but it does nothing. In fact it seems that DEBIAN/shlibs file should be generated by dh_makeshlibs, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a versioned dependency, put one in `debian/control`.

```
Depends: zs-boost (>= 1.71.0)
```

The versioned dependency on a specific version of `libc6` you see in the generated `shlibs` is ultimately down to a similar explicit declaration determined (usually conservatively and with great care) by a package maintainer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I specifically noted that I don't want to create dependencies by hand - version of libc6 for is generated automatically for my package and it definitely isn't determined with great care by package maintainer, as I am this package's maintainer and as you can see I only specified `${shlibs:Depends}` in `Depends` section of my package. I assumed that adding `-V` to `dh_makeshlibs` would, as described on program's manpage add pacakge's version automatically, but it isn't so.

Comment: If the `libc6` dependency were blindly generated from whichever version you happened to have installed, you'd see something like `(==2.28-10)`. The `>= 2.9` corresponds to an ABI change which the maintainer deemed to be significant enough to warrant prohibiting earlier versions.

Comment: Ok, sorry, only after experimenting more I realised that you meant not `shlibs` file in package that lacked dependencies, but `shlibs` in `zs-boost` package. After overriding call to `dh_makeshlibs` and rebuilding package (but earlier gcc 9.2.0, but earlier...), I finally got proper dependencies in my final package. This is great. Thank you.

Comment: Your edit suggestion was rejected, and I can't say I really want to incorporate it here. Maybe post a separate answer if you think it's important.

Comment: I thought it is important, because right now your answer is misleading in a sense that if some (like me) is not intimately familiar with deb building, "shlibs" that you mention is assumed (wrongly) to be from "package", not from "zs-boost", so package that "package" depends on. I already know how it works so I don't really care, I just thought that fuller answer will be more useful in the future.